# gremlin intersection operation

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I'm using the gremlin console v3.3.1. 
Using the "Modern" graph from the tutorial:
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/getting-started/

Creating the graph with this:

```
gremlin>graph = TinkerFactory.createModern()
gremlin>g = graph.traversal()
```

I can find all the people that know "vadas" like this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('person').has('name', 'vadas').in('knows').hasLabel('person').valueMap()
```

And I can find all the people that created the software "lop" with this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('software').has('name', 'lop').in('created').hasLabel('person').valueMap()
```

I can find all the people that know "vadas" OR created "lop" with a union operation:

```
g.V().union(
g.V().hasLabel('person').has('name', 'vadas').in('knows').hasLabel('person'),
g.V().hasLabel('software').has('name','lop').in('created').hasLabel('person')
).dedup().valueMap()
```

But I can't figure out how to find all the people that know "vadas" AND created "lop". Essentially I want an INTERSECT operation (I think), but there is no such thing that I can find.

Any help?

Comment: Related thread on Gremlin users mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/6_MRJxBnivo/wT_71IAzCwAJ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are likely other ways to do this, but here's a few that I came up with. The first uses `match()` step:

```
gremlin> g.V().match(
......1>   __.as('a').out('created').has('software','name','lop'),
......2>   __.as('a').out('knows').has('person','name','josh')).
......3>   select('a')
==>v[1]
```

The second just uses `and()` step:

```
gremlin> g.V().and(
......1>   out('created').has('software','name','lop'),
......2>   out('knows').has('person','name','vadas'))
==>v[1]
```

both could potentially require full scans of of all vertices (not sure what graph databases would optimize those traversals to use indices), so I also tried this:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','vadas').in('knows').hasLabel('person').
......1>   V().has('software','name','lop').in('created').hasLabel('person').
......2>   path().
......3>   filter(union(range(local,1,2), 
......4>                range(local,3,4)).
......5>          fold().
......6>          dedup(local).
......7>          count(local).is(1)).
......8>   tail(local)
==>v[1]
```

It basically grabs the `path()` of the first two traversals over `V()` and then analyzes it to look for matches betweeen path positions. As soon as I saw that traversal, I realized it could all be simplified down to:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','vadas').in('knows').hasLabel('person').as('a').
......1>   V().has('software','name','lop').in('created').hasLabel('person').as('b').
......2>   select('a').
......3>   where('a',eq('b'))
==>v[1]
```

Comment: thx for the assistance. Followup question. Suppose in the above answer Vadas is very popular, and 100s of thousands of people know him. But that only very few people created 'lop'. Would a graph DB (DSE Graph for instance) be able to be smart executing those queries?

Comment: great! now I need a query that can dynamically intersect 1-n edge traversals